# How to access array returned by a json call

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, dictionary

How to access the typeMatch which is of type array from the below object using javascript.

Here is what i am trying and able to access message but not typeMatch

```
$.getJSON(uriGetTypeMatch)
    .done(function (data) {
        document.getElementById('MessageBox').innerHTML = data.message;
    });
```

Return object

```
    Sample:
{
  "typeMatch": {
    "sample string 1": 2,
    "sample string 3": 4
  },
  "message": "sample string 2"  
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You're calling getJSON() and getting back XML. Malformed XML at that.  Seems like a problem to me.

Comment: thats xml format returned by web api...here is the json format for the same@DavidL

Comment: `typeMatch` isn't an array in your sample result, it's an object. You'd access it the same way you're accessing message (`data.typeMatch`)

Comment: I am not able to access the object using data.typeMatch all it returns is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

On your main form put this on the top:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

You can download and add this dll to your References from here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

After that create simple class with all your objects in Json, paste this on your main form:

```
#Region " - Classes - "
Public Class JSON_result
    Public typeMatch As String
    Public sample_string_1 As String
    Public sample_string_3 As String
    Public message As String
End Class
#End Region
```

You can add more objects, depends on your Json.

To Get Data from your Json Link use this:

```
  Private Sub GetJsonData()
    Try
        Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim jsonlink As String = "http://yourJsonlink.com/data.txt"
        Dim jsondata As String
        jsondata = wc.DownloadString(jsonlink)
        TextBox1.Text = jsondata.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  End Sub
```

After that the final is to Load and show Data and values into textboxes:

```
    Private Sub LoadDataToTextBoxes()
    Try
        Dim obj As JSON_result
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_result)(Me.TexTbox1.Text)

        typeMatchTXT = obj.typeMatch
        sample_string_1TXT = obj.sample_string_1
        sample_string_3TXT = obj.sample_string_3
        messageTXT = obj.message
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
   End Sub
```

You can make `TextBox1.Visible = False` on your main app, to hide Json
loaded data from the link.